# Office-js as angular service instead of declare const Office variable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, outlook, office-js

I'm looking for an article that will point me to learn to inject Office-js as an angular service instead of declaring the `Office` variable in the main.ts as something like: `declare const Office: any;` as this is hard to test.

What I did is something like when using the `window.Office` as a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class OfficeService {

    constructor() {
        if (Office === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Office object is not available.');
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

So is there a proper way to do this and would be easier also to test?

Comment: The following link might be something useful to look into: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT there is none in the document pinpointing me to my question.

Comment: Hi rpmansion, we don't have an npm package for Office.js, which you need in order to inject a service. I'm not aware of a way to inject a library that's hosted on a CDN.